# Passing Coordinates between Views

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

I have two views :
1) Mapview 
2) DetailView

I want to pass the coordinates from the map view to the detail view.
coordinates.latitude and coordinates.longtitude

How do i go about passing the coordinates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+objective-c+pass+value+between+views

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could do this. One of which is with a property. So you would have the property declaration in the map view and then be able to access it via someMapView.propertyName.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do i go about doing that? I am not very sure Thank you for ur help

Comment: In you header: @property(nonatomic, retain) SomeType *someVariable That's how you declare a property in the header. Be sure you use @synthesize in the implementation file and release it in the dealloc; I am assuming you are not using ARC.